# Forward port to LXC guest using UFW

Tags: ufw, lxc, port-forwarding

I am trying to forward port 2222 on my host 192.168.2.252 to a LXC guest on 10.0.3.11. How do I do it using the UFW-framework?

In other words I want to do this but with the ufw-framework.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.11:2222
```

Regards,
MB

Answer (score 4):

Add to the top of the `/etc/ufw/before.rules` before the `*filter` (top of file):

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.11:2222
COMMIT
```

then restart/reload the firewall

```
sudo ufw disable && sudo ufw enable
```

Since we're using other that ufw's chains `ufw-before-*, ufw-after-* and ufw-reject-*`, we have to change `MANAGE_BUILTINS=no` to `MANAGE_BUILTINS=yes` in file `/etc/default/ufw. Check [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ufw/+bug/364558) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Steve Zhan's answer is correct, one more thing to do if you're on Vagrant is to change `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"` to `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"` in `/etc/default/ufw`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few more configuration steps that are needed to allow general traffic to flow; simply adding the pre-routing lines are insufficient.

Assuming your UFW rules are not already heavily modified, the following should be sufficient:

At the top of `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, *before* the `*filter` section

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.11:2222
COMMIT
```

And near the bottom, *before* the final `COMMIT`:

```
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -i enp0s8 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -i enp0s8 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 67 -i enp0s8 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 67 -i enp0s8 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

And also, in the `/etc/ufw/after.rules`, again *before* the `*filter` section you need

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```